# Capturar tráfego com Wireshark

Tags: segurança, redes

Estou tentando monitorar uma conexão externa com o meu servidor (na mesma rede da minha maquina) porem no wireshark só mostra os tráfegos da minha maquina, estou usando a interface local com o promiscuous mode

Comment: a "interface local" por acaso é a localhost ? se for, então você não vai conseguir monitorar a conexão externa mesmo, você tem que usar a interface de rede por onde a conexão externa está entrando

Answer (score 0):

Estar na mesma rede não garante que seja possível capturar o tráfego de seu servidor e outros hosts da sua rede interna, existem meios ilícitos de fazer isso e não vou entrar em detalhes.

As maneiras corretas de capturar o tráfego que precisa é:

- Executar um sniffer diretamente no seu servidor e verificar se o
  tráfego esperado está ocorrendo (óbvio que vc tem que ter acesso ao servidor).
- Executar um sniffer no Gateway que o seu servidor usa, desta maneira 
  você vai pegar todo o tráfego de entrada e saída entre os dois hosts 
  que passam pelo gateway (óbvio vc tem que ter acesso ao gateway).
- Se o Switch que o seu servidor está fisicamente conectado via cabo de
  rede for gerenciável, layer3 ou acima disso é bem provável que vc consiga fazer um port mirror(espelhar porta), dessa maneira vc consegue dizer para o switch transferir todo o tráfego de determinadas portas, isso faz com que você consiga interceptar via sniffer tudo que estaria entrando e saído na porta do switch que está o seu servidor (óbvio tem q ter um switch com opção de port mirror e acesso físico nesse switch).

Antigamente quando os ativos de redes eram Hubs e não Switches, era possível conseguir informações de tráfego ocorrendo na rede, isso era um perigo, qualquer computador na rede poderia interceptar informações.

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo das restrições que você tenha, também é possível rodar um `tcpdump` no servidor e salvar a saída em um arquivo para depois abrí-lo no `wireshark` e fazer uma leitura mais "visual".
Talvez não esteja vendo o tráfego por configurações do seu switch ou rede local.